# build using npm failed

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

Build project with nodejs failed

OS is CentOS 7.4.1708 X64

Download and extract node-v8.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
then, add the dir to the PATH

```
[root in ~]# node -v
v8.12.0
[root in ~]# npm -v
6.4.1
```

My project directory is :

```
[root in /web/www/camp_admin_test/trunk/camp-vue]# ls -l
total 604
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Jul 26 17:43 build
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Jul 26 17:43 config
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Jul 26 17:43 dist
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    276 Jul 26 17:43 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 998 root root  36864 Jul 26 17:53 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2435 Jul 26 17:53 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 537923 Jul 26 17:53 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    557 Jul 26 17:43 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root   4096 Jul 26 17:43 src
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Jul 26 17:43 static
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Jul 26 17:43 test
```

In this dir, run **npm run dev**
failed, the output is :

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 13 errors                                                                     18:13:35

This dependency was not found:

* @/pages/common/Nodata in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/pages/MicLesson/LessionType.vue, ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/pages/MicLesson/Lessions.vue and 11 others

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/pages/common/Nodata
```

I follow its suggestion:

> npm install --save @/pages/common/Nodata

and get this:

```
[root in /web/www/camp_admin_test/trunk/camp-vue]# npm install --save @/pages/common/Nodata
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@/pages/common/Nodata" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-26T10_14_59_597Z-debug.log
```

The log file is :

```
[root in /web/www/camp_admin_test/trunk/camp-vue]# cat /root/.npm/_logs/2019-07-26T10_14_59_597Z-deb
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   '@/pages/common/Nodata' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose npm-session ff98e06075a6fb08
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for file:@/pages/common/Nodata Could not install from "@/pages/common/Nodata" as it does not contain a package.json file.
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3929ms
10 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/web/www/camp_admin_test/trunk/camp-vue/@/pages/common/Nodata/package.json'
11 verbose cwd /web/www/camp_admin_test/trunk/camp-vue
12 verbose Linux 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
13 verbose argv "/usr/local/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/local/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "@/pages/common/Nodata"
14 verbose node v8.12.0
15 verbose npm  v6.4.1
16 error code ENOLOCAL
17 error Could not install from "@/pages/common/Nodata" as it does not contain a package.json file.
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

npm-check-updates upgrades your package.json dependencies to the latest versions, ignoring specified versions.

Run npm install to update your installed packages and package-lock.json.

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install --no-bin-links
npm update
npm run dev
```

For more information you can refer npm documentation:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. The output is as same as before.  I will try other ways.